# Testing react components that use context

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a system that makes heavy use of internationalisation, so am placing my intl object into context.  However, I cannot figure out how to mock the context when testing.

For completion, here is the essence of my intl provider:

```js
export default class Intl extends Component {
  getChildContext() {
    return {
      intl: {
        //some stuffs
      }
    };
  }

  static childContextTypes = {
    intl: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.intl = props.intl;
  }

  render() {
    let {
      children
    } = this.props;
    return (Children.only(children));
  }
};
```

I tried two ways of  ensuring my object have intl when they are tested:

1. Widen the search for my intl object, which is painful

   `const intl = this.context.intl || this.props.intl`
2. Wrap the component in a provider for testing.  This causes problems with react testing since it only renders one layer of JSX

```
    <Intl>
      <SomeComponent />
    <Intl>
```

Is there really no way of injecting Context in these scenarios?

Thanks

Comment: `This causes problems with react testing`.  Only if you use shallow render.  Otherwise, it should be fine to do this.

Comment: What I am trying to do is actually call a function in my component to ensure its logic is working correctly, so I'm not sure I can shallow render.  (Sorry if this is sounding dumb, I am very new to react testing)

Comment: what I meant was that only shallow rendering renders one layer deep.  Usually, if you use `renderIntoDocument` it will render all layers and then you can select a component by type.